# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRadius' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

My code works when I deploy it locally, but it doesn't work when I deploy it to a github page. In the calculateRadius() function I call the setRadius() function which assigns a radius to a google maps circle. When I run call this function I get an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRadius' of undefined" Please see code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="datetime">
      Number: <input type="number" id="areaChange" value="0">
        </br>
      <form onsubmit="calculateRadius(); return false;">
        Select a date after January, 1 2010
        </br>
        Date: <input type="date" id="date" value="" min="2010-01-01">
        <button id="btn">Click</button>
      </form>
      <button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
        <p id="data"></p>

    </div>
<script>
var areaRate = 1648.91;
var circle;
var today;
var date1;
var date2;
var timeDiff;
var diffDays;
var timePassed;

var interval;
var intervalRate = 1000;

function setRadius() {
    circle.setRadius(parseInt(document.getElementById("areaChange").value, 10));
}

function calculateRadius() {
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = document.getElementById("date").value;
    today = new Date();
    date1 = new Date(document.getElementById("date").value);
    date2 = today;
    timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000));
    timePassed = areaRate * diffDays;

    console.log(intervalRate);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        var radius = Math.sqrt(timePassed / Math.PI);
        document.getElementById("areaChange").value = radius;
        console.log(timePassed);

        setRadius();
        timePassed += areaRate;
    }, intervalRate);
}

document.getElementById("resetBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log(interval);
});

function initMap() {
    var styler = [{
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative.country",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
        }, {
            "invert_lightness": true
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }, {
            "invert_lightness": true
        }, {
            "weight": 1.43
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
        }, {
            "color": "#44a9b0"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#e3e0bf"
        }]
    }];

    var detroit = {
        lat: 42.271084,
        lng: -83.737277
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: detroit,
        styles: styler
    });
    var pos;

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        map.setCenter(pos);
        circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            center: pos,
            radius: parseInt(document.getElementById("areaChange").value),
            editable: false,
            draggable: true,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: 'transparent',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF4136',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        });

    });

    var time = document.getElementById('areaChange');
    time.addEventListener('input', setRadius);

}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: It seems it is a problem from GitHub pages. I will host my page in a different host.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
function setRadius(){
 if(circle)
  circle.setRadius(parseInt(document.getElementById("areaChange").value, 10));
}
```

The problem is that when `setInterval` is calling `setRadius()` value of `circle` is `undefined` by default because of `var circle;`

Comment: This won't solve the issue as if the circle variable is undefined it will never be executed, this will just prevent the error to be displayed.

Comment: OP is declaring the value latter on .

circle = new google.maps.Circle({

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am not getting a typeError but the circle is not showing. Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a race condition. Probably the circus variable is not initialized by the time you want to access it.

Its most likely navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is taking a while before executing the callback declaring the circle variable or maybe just failing so this is never declared. Not an expert in maps but do you need a developer key or something like that that might not allow you to use their API in production or any non local domain?

Why dont you try to add a breakpoint with chrome devtools inspector?

Comment: If this is the case I shouldn't be able to run the function in my localhost. The problem is that the code works in my localhost but not when I deploy it to a github page.

Comment: Check what I told you about the google key of credential to be able to use it in production. Maybe so far you are just allow to use it locally. Did you try to add some breakpoints, console logs etc to see how it behaves ?

Comment: Javier,
Thanks for your answer. It is not the API key. I took it out of the post. I've made some tweaks and the error message changed to circle.setFunction is not a function.